# Why does this simple SELECT MySQL query hangs when the conditions are put together using the OR operator?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this simple MySQL query that mysteriously hangs forever.

**Query #1** The following query works (using the first license only), and returning empty set as expected.

```
SELECT c_desc, c_timestamp FROM t_usage WHERE c_license_sign='license001' ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

**Query #2** The following query works (using the second license only), and returning 1 row as expected.

```
SELECT c_desc, c_timestamp FROM t_usage WHERE c_license_sign='license002' ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

**Query #3** The following query **hangs** forever (using the "first license `OR` second license"), and I have to use Ctrl+C to get out. Although there doesn't seem to have an increase in CPU nor memory usage while hanging.

```
SELECT c_desc, c_timestamp FROM t_usage WHERE c_license_sign='license001' OR
c_license_sign='license002' ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

This is the EXPLAIN for query#3

```
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t_usage | index | licenses      | idx_timestamp | 6       | NULL |  706 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

**Query #4** HOWEVER, this query works (using `OR` but removed the `c_desc`), and returning 1 row as expected.

```
SELECT c_timestamp FROM t_usage WHERE c_license_sign='license001' OR
c_license_sign='license002' ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

Keeping `c_desc` and removing the `c_timestamp` still hangs.

**So, why does having `OR` and `c_desc` together makes it hangs?**

This is the table schema (I removed some unnecessary columns). No primary key (intended). It has more than 1.5 million records.

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| c_custid       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c_license_sign | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| c_desc         | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c_timestamp    | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It has 2 indices:

1. `idx_timestamp` index on `c_timestamp` only
2. `licenses` index is composite on (`c_license_sign`, `c_timestamp`)

I am using mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: How many records are in the `t_usage` table?

Comment: 1,525,364 records.

Comment: Is the explain plan for the second `OR` query, or for the first two queries?

Comment: the EXPLAIN is for the query that hangs (type=index). For the first and second queries, the type=ref and the key=licenses

Comment: Please post COMPLETE TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE t_usage; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 't_usage';  for analysis.

Comment: Please consider trying, 
    SELECT c_desc, c_timestamp, c_license_sign FROM t_usage WHERE c_license_sign='license001' OR
c_license_sign='license002' ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;  
    because you will probaby need to know who the data is from.

Comment: I finally found a solution. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always going to take latest record, better add `DESC` in `c_timestamp` column in `licences` index.

```
INDEX licences (c_license_sign, c_timestamp DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer my own question after I found a solution for it.
The solution: use explicit index.
The query which will work is

```
SELECT c_desc, c_timestamp FROM t_usage USE INDEX(licenses)
WHERE c_license_sign='license001' OR c_license_sign='license002'
ORDER BY c_timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

Explicitly using the other index (idx_timestamp) will hang the same way as if without using an explicit index.

Unfortunately, I cannot explain why. The thing that maybe can be used as the hint is the EXPLAIN result. It says that the `possible_keys` is only `licenses`, but the actual `key` being used is `idx_timestamp` (how come?).

At least, if anyone stumble on similar issue like this, you can try to use an explicit index.